# How to store app settings(App.config) in Xamarin

Tags: c#, android, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am just getting started on Xamarin and decided to use Xamarin Forms. Traditionally in .Net projects we have a app.config or web.config. How is this done for Mobile applications.

And how are the settings updated for each environment. I have used config transforms. Is there anything similar in Xamarin?

Comment: I looked at this. This is for App Settings. From my understanding it is used for the user application settings. I am asking for a place to add service URI's, any api keys etc. Can this be used for those too?

Comment: Bundle a Json/XML file into your app, read it on startup.

Comment: https://developer.xamarin.com/guides/xamarin-forms/working-with/files/

Comment: I read about using a file. Just want to find out if there is a more elegant way if doing this. May be something inbuilt that I overlooked

Comment: You can go with the fike only if you are putting there non sensitive information otherwise I suggest you to stick with the platform specifics mechanisms to save user settings in a more secure way. Please note thay your application can be opened anytime and any file would be visible.

Comment: You can also use this great plugin that is gonna help you to have everything in a single file and still using platform specific settings service: https://github.com/jamesmontemagno/SettingsPlugin

Comment: @katie77, Like you I also just started on Xamarin. Can you please let us know if you were able to solve this issue.